# How can I fill two entities with data after i click submit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am looking for a solution all day, but I still can not find anything.

When I create a book, how can I create an author and assign it to a book at the same time?

I have two entities

Book

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String title;

@ManyToOne
private Author author;
}
```

Author

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Author {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private Set<Book> books;
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

private BookRepository bookRepository;

public BookController(BookRepository bookRepository) {
    this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/booklist", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String bookList(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("books", bookRepository.findAll());
    return "booklist";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add")
public String addBook(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
    return "addbook";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(Book book){
    bookRepository.save(book);        
    return "redirect:booklist";
}
}
```

VIEW

```
<body>

<div>
    <form th:object="${book}" th:action="@{save}" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="title">Title</label> 
        <input type="text" id="title"
            th:field="*{title}" />
        <label for="author">Author</label>
        <input type="text" id="author" th:field="*{author.name}" />

        <input type="submit" value="Save"></input>
    </form>
</div>


</body>
```

When I try to create a book I got this error 
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

After i click submit button 
[it should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4IKP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding cascede to Author in entity like this

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String title;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Author author;

}
```

or use prepersist annotation on your entity

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    //check author is exist if not persist the author first
}
```